# Android Studio 1.4 doesn't allow Android Module dependency on Java Test modules

Tags: android-studio, gradle, junit, junit4, robolectric

I have a set of Test (for my Android App), that could run in Junit approach (right click on the testClass file and run it) in Android Studio. It does depends on Android Module which and uses Robolectric. It worked fines until Android Studio 1.3.1.

However when I migrate over to Android Studio 1.4, when I sync my Gradle file, there's this warning

```
Warning:Ignoring dependency of module 'app' on module 'unit-tests'. Java modules cannot depend on Android modules
```

With that, my test can also no longer get triggered, as all my Android classes e.g. AppCompat is not detectable anymore.

Part of my gradle code as below where :app is my android module.

```
def androidModule = project(':app')

dependencies {
    testCompile androidModule
    //... some other dependency
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5'
    //... some other dependency
}
```

Found this link on the same issue https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=188880&q=label%3AReportedBy-Developer&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars.

Could someone shed some light on this, if this is intended new Android Studio 1.4 behaviour, something wrong in my gradle file, or just a new Android Studio 1.4 bug?

Comment: That's interesting that it happens with 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4' too. I have robolectric v3.0, which also fails.

Comment: I also updated to Android Studio v1.5 Preview, and it also doesn't work.

Comment: This kinda sucks big time... wth

Comment: Ya, @worked, this is a big step back. I still hold on to my 1.3.1 because of this...  Perhaps you could consider upvote the question/issue above to get more attention to it.

Comment: it seems the same problem persist in 2.0 preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Work-arounds

#### Revert to Android Studio v1.3.1

It seems that, pending a fix from Robolectric, the only workaround to use Android Studio's GUI is to revert back to Android Studio v1.3.1 (the last version that worked, as noted) that worked without the error messages.

This can be downloaded here: http://tools.android.com/download/studio/stable

#### Use Gradle to execute unit tests

An alternative is to run the unit tests directly in Gradle, via the command line. From the root of the project (i.e. the same directory where the settings.gradle, and local.properties files are), run:

```
 ./gradlew test
```

Comment: Cool Thanks CJBS!. These are all my workaround approach I'm using now. Thanks for the confirmation. Upvote and TIck it :)